# How can I change the datasource for a kanban of syncfusion with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syncfusion

This program looks in the datasource the 'Estado' field, depending the number it adds different icons, for example if the Estado = 2 he adds in the field ClassName, estado-1, estado-2. To make this I made this JS, that in console writes well, but it doesn't apply the changes to the datasource so the CSS not working correctly :(
The JS:

```
   cardSettings: {
        contentField: 'Cantidad',
        headerField: 'Title',
        footerCssField: 'ClassName'
    },

kanbanObj.cardRendered = function (args) {
//Writes the values in classname like estado-1, estado-2... depending of the number of estado
function addEstadoClasses(estado, currentClassName) {
        var estadoNum = parseInt(estado, 10);
        for (var i = 1; i <= estadoNum; i++) {
            if (currentClassName !== "") { 
                currentClassName += ', ';
            }
            currentClassName += 'e-estado-' + i;
        }
        return currentClassName;
    }

    //Load the CSS after the JS
    function loadEstadoStylesheet() {
        var cssId = 'estadoStylesheet';
        if (!document.getElementById(cssId)) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var link = document.createElement('link');
            link.id = cssId;
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'estilos-estados.css'; 
            link.media = 'all';
            head.appendChild(link);
        }
    }                

var currentClassName = args.data.ClassName || '';

//Adding the values of classname depending the Estado value
  var estadoValue = args.data.Estado;
 if (estadoValue !== null && estadoValue !== undefined) {
     var estadoValues = estadoValue.split(',').map(estado => estado.trim());
     estadoValues.forEach(estado => {
        currentClassName = addEstadoClasses(estado, currentClassName);
     });  
            
     args.data.ClassName = currentClassName;  
     //To load the css
     setTimeout(function () {
       loadEstadoStylesheet();
     }, 11110);
```

If I write manually in the datasource the CSS works correctly but not with the JS adding it.
CSS:

```
e-kanban .e-card-footer-css {
    align-self: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-image: url(https://syncfusion.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/trivial.svg);
}

.e-estado-3 {
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-image: url(https://syncfusion.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/critical.svg) !important;
}
```

Datasource example:

```
{
        "Id": "Task 8",
        "Title": "CIRON",
        "Status": "Lunes",
        "Summary": "Test the application in the IE browser.",
        "Type": "Clorato",
        "Estado": "0",
        "Tags": "Review,IE",
        "Estimate": 5.5,
        "Assignee": "Margaret hamilt",
        "RankId": 3,
        "Cantidad": 23000,
        "Color": "#02897B",
        "ClassName": "" //The field we want to change
    },
```

I tried different methods but nothing worked, with the load for the css, changing into a new field and calling the css from the JS. Also changing to databound from datarendered and different codes.